# Prefix.pch: how to not use it for certain files?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, objective-c++, precompiled-headers

How can I avoid that the import statements given in my prefix.pch file are added to a certain .h file named `VMKChilkatWrapper.h`?

I've tried the following:

```
#if !__has_include("VMKChilkatWrapper.h")
#if !strcmp(__FILE__, "VMKChilkatWrapper.h")
#if !strcmp(__BASE_FILE__, "VMKChilkatWrapper.h")
```

But even after hours of trying, I cannot make it work. Is this possible?

**Why do I want to do this?**

I have a few `.mm` files (Objective-C++). When I import Objective-C classes into them, I can no longer use `@import`.

Therefore, I have created a wrapper class, which is the only class imported into my `.mm` files.

I also use `#ifdef __OBJC__` in  my Prefix.pch file to avoid that my Objective-C header files are being imported into my `.mm` files.

However, `#ifdef __OBJC__` does not prevent my `Prefix.pch` file from being included in `VMKChilkatWrapper`. Therefore, the `@import` directive does not work for any files that are in my `Prefix.pch` file.

At the moment, I believe that the best solution would be to get rid of the import statements in my `Prefix.pch` file.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why imported prefix is bothering you?

Comment: I have added an explanation to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggested not to use `@import`. Use instead old fashion `#import`.
If you have difficulties with that, then use `@import`'s only exactly where you need them, like in `Swift`.

There is also one possible solution.
Put yours import in `#ifdef __OBJC__ #ifndef __cplusplus` `#endif #endif` block.
Example

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
#ifndef __cplusplus
@import ...
#endif
#endif
```

Comment: Adding `#ifndef __cplusplus` made it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The prefix header is added to every implementation file before it is compiled. At this time there is no information about other header files included in that file is available.

If you need this you are doing it wrong. The only purpose of prefix headers is to speed up the compilation by precompiling some framework headers. Just adding stuff there so it is available in every implementation file is an anti-pattern.